# jQuery form validation; field required if checkbox selected

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm currently working with this;
http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/

I'm trying to add validation so if a user checks the Location box, the "L2" field would have to be required. How can I achieve this with this plugin? Would I have to mix in the checkbox expression?;

```
expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)) return true; else return false;",
```

Here's the plugin functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#v1").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter your name"
                });
            });
</script>
```

Here's the form

```
<form method="post" id="contactform" action="/form.php" >
<h5>Category:</h5>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="Location" value="Checked" onclick="toggle_visibility('f1');"> <span class="a1">- Location</span><br><div id="f1" style="display:none">Where are you located?<br /><input name="L2" id="L2" type="text"  /></div></p>

<h5>Name:</h5>
<p><input name="Name" id="v1" type="text" /></p>
<p><div><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></div></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Use depends option.  You can read it on the jquery validation - options page.

Comment: I would use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` instead of the inline `on` attributes.

Comment: @Jules I'm pretty new to java, I checked out the dependency option, added this with id inline '$("#Location").blur(function() { $("#L2").valid(); });' I'm wondering since I'm using that plugin from geektantra, would that make a difference in terms of how the functions are?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Could attachevent be used to combine the toggle visibility code + the validation method same as "v1"? So it acts as a onclick

Comment: @Jake Yes. In jQuery: `$('input[name="Location"]').click(function() { toggle_visibility('f1'); });`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Thanks a lot!!!! That worked great! One problem though, when the checkbox is clicked again to uncheck, the form doesn't submit because it makes the field required, is there a way to make it so when its unchecked the field would be not required?

Comment: @Jake What does "it makes the field required" mean? Specifically, what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
rules: {
      fieldName: {
        required: {       
          depends: function() {
            return $("input[name='checkbox']:checked")
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a newbie with javascript, would that work with the plugin though? I tried as a test '$("#myinput").rules("add", { minlength: 2 });' but that didn't seem to work

Comment: or can try this `$("input[name='checkbox']").is(":checked")` and remove *element* un-used variable

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Sudhir's answer didn't work for me - I had to modify it:

```
rules: {
  fieldName: {
    required: {       
      depends: function(element) {
        return $("input[name='checkbox']:checked").length == 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudhir's answer is correct.  All you have to do is use it as options when initialising the validation.

```
var opt = {};//copy from Sudhir's post of course change the field name as required.
$("form").validate(opt);
```